# Live 3d view pov-ray and tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, povray

I am trying to make a GUI in python (tkinter). I have successfully created the application such that I have a scene rendered by POV-ray. I press button "move to left" and this changes the camera location  in the .pov file, re-renders the scene and shows it in the GUI(same for rotation and zoom in/out).

But I would like to make interactive. i.e use mouse to interact with the scene completely just like a matplotlib 3D graph but for ray-rendering.

How to go about solving this problem ?

The Scenes have values of location as

Img_1 location <0,0,-10>

Img_2 location <0,-10,-10>

Img_3 location <25,0,-10>

**PS**

I am not trying to import matplotlib plot in my GUI. It is just for refrence to share what I want to achieve with my rendered scenes.

[[image: img1]]img1[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANj5I.png)

[[image: img2]]img2[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Hjb.png)

[[image: img3]]img3[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JnNj.png)

Comment: `root.bind('<Button-1>', function_name)` to run function when you press mouse button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mouse events `<Motion>` and `<Button-1>`, (and others) to run functions which will change content in window.

---

**EDIT:** Examples show how to use `bind()` to run functions when you use mouse and how to calculate `diff_x`, `diff_y` to move objects. You have to uses own functions with `bind()` which will use `diff_x`, `diff_y` to move POVRay camera and render new image. And then you will have to replace image on canvas. But I will use canvas objects instead of POVRay to show how it can change when mouse is moving.

---

This example moves rectangle when you move mouse, and it changes color when you click button.
But you can run functions which move, zoom or rotate rendered image.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def move_item(event):
    canvas.coords(item, event.x-50, event.y-50, event.x+50, event.y+50)

def change_item(event):
    if canvas.itemcget(item, 'fill') == 'red':
        canvas.itemconfig(item, fill='blue')
    else:        
        canvas.itemconfig(item, fill='red')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=300)
canvas.pack()

item = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill='red')

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", change_item)
canvas.bind("<Motion>", move_item)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** Example which uses `<B1-Motion>`, `<Shift-B1-Motion>`, `<Control-B1-Motion>` to move objects:

- in all directions (`left mouse button`),
- only horizontally (`Shift` + `left mouse button`)
- only vertically (`Control` + `left mouse button`).

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def move_item(event):
    global old_x
    global old_y    
    diff_x = event.x - old_x
    diff_y = event.y - old_y
    for item in items:
        canvas.move(item, diff_x, diff_y)
    old_x = event.x
    old_y = event.y

def move_horizontal(event):
    global old_x
    diff_x = event.x - old_x
    for item in items:
        canvas.move(item, diff_x, 0)
    old_x = event.x

def move_vertical(event):
    global old_y
    diff_y = event.y - old_y
    for item in items:
        canvas.move(item, 0, diff_y)
    old_y = event.y

def save_position(event):
    global old_x
    global old_y    
    old_x = event.x
    old_y = event.y
    
# --- main ---

old_x = 0
old_y = 0
# init
root = tk.Tk()

# create canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=300)
canvas.pack()

# create objects
items = [
    canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 130, 130, fill='red'),
    canvas.create_rectangle(200, 100, 230, 130, fill='blue'),
    canvas.create_rectangle(100, 200, 130, 230, fill='yellow'),
]

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", save_position)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", move_item)
canvas.bind("<Shift-B1-Motion>", move_horizontal)
canvas.bind("<Control-B1-Motion>", move_vertical)
# start program
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply but unfortunately this will not work in my case as I am moving a rendered POV-ray image's camera. I've edited the question maybe it will help to clarify my goal

Comment: it shows how to uses `bind()` to run function when you use mouse - you have to use own functions with `bind()` which will render image with different camera position. It also shows how to calculate `diff_x`, `diff_y` which you can use to move your camera in POV-Ray.

Comment: I understand the point but how to add z-axis for 3D in the above case

Comment: you can use `<B1-Motion>` to change your `x` and `y` and `<Shift-B1-Motion>` to change your `z`. And then you can render it.

Comment: I never check it but using `<Button-4>` and `<Button-5>` you can use `wheel` in mouse to change value - ie. you could change your `z`. [Using the Mouse Wheel with Tkinter (Python)](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/217059/using-the-mouse-wheel-with-tkinter-python)